# Flash stage to Flashbuilder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I have a fairly complex (well, for me) project in Flash Pro CS6 for iOS and Android. All of the code is in AS3 - mostly one big file since I suck at OOP. I have a ton of stuff on the Stage for the main layout - most of it symbols, but some not.

Anyway, I am interested in moving to FlashBuilder and am looking for the best path to get the stuff moved over and up and running.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no good way to do this. There is no "stage" in FlashBuilder, beyond the `Stage` datatype in AS3, of course. Everything that is on the stage or in the library in Flash Pro **must** be recreated using code or through loading via the Embed metadata tag. This includes all buttons, symbols, images, fonts, etc.

Honestly, unless this is a requirement or you have hit a point where you cannot go any further with the project without moving to a more OOP approach, you should just leave well enough alone. This is going to require a ton of work to do; there is no way to convert a FLA to a FlashBuilder project and you cannot simply copy/paste code because all of your references to objects on the stage and in the library will be absolutely useless.

Comment: Everything here is valid, though I'm bit put-off that the OPs question was closed, as this is a somewhat valid answer.  It is a huge effort to switch between the two, you can export assets created in one or the other and then load those assets as modules (which still creates some complications).  Anyhow just saying this is a valid answer and I think although a bit naive a valid question.  I would also suggest to the OP checking out http://flex.apache.org/doc-getstarted.html but consider it starting from scratch (AS3 syntax is the same, libraries vary wildly)

Comment: @shaunhusain actually, this answer is not 100% correct. the embed tag is not the only way to go and in fact is the worst. This is what SWC is designed for and the conversion to that is quite simple as long as there is zero timeline code. And this question was closed most-likely due to the very last line.

Comment: @The_asMan, yup I understand what you're saying and nothing stated so far here was 100% correct (or best case for any given scenario).  But I was taking the OPs question as a bit more of a general, I want to get from A to B how do I get there, and this answer being there is no direct route (but offering options).  Even if there isn't a single correct answer I don't see how having guidance within the SO posts is harmful... anyhow no big deal, I just disagree with the community on occasion.